# Suppressing log output from an iOS library

Tags: ios, ios8, nslog

I would like to intercept and filter out logging statements from an iOS library (the Twilio SDK). It doesn't provide a way to set a logging level unfortunately, so I am looking for a way to intercept all logging statements and prevent some of them from going out to the system/console logs.

Comment: are you compiling it yourself?

Comment: Is this just for debugging or do you plan on shipping the code? If it's just for debugging, try writing your own NSLog function. Depending on the load order, yours will most likely override the system one. You can then just use printf to output to the console instead.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I am not compiling the library, it's not open-source

Comment: @EricS: I'm looking to suppress this in production code too

Comment: I think writing your own NSLog routine will work even in shipping code, but I'm not 100% certain of it. In a pinch you might be able to modify the library by hand, but that's pretty ugly too. Open it in Hex Fiend and try replacing "NSLog" with "NSLOG" and then add a dummy NSLOG routine to your app, like void NSLOG( const NSString *str, ... ).